# Can I use waitfor to detect task or timeout

Tags: c, circuit

I am writing a program in Dynamic C for a `rabbit BL2600` board.

The program is controlling a pressure chamber a top chamber and a bottom chamber with metal in between checking for perforation.  I have a sensor on my pressure regulator and a sensor reading the opposite chamber.

I have a fail function that sees if the chambers are leaking from one side to the other.  when I pressurize the chamber I am using a `waitfor` to wait until the pressure in the chamber gets within 10% of what I am setting the pressure to.  I want it to wait until that happens, but I also want to make sure that it does not wait forever and that it will detect a leak to outside the chamber. Basically I want it to `waitfor` the pressure to build or xx amount of time and if xx amount of time passes return basically a failure.

I am a beginner at programming and this may be a simple solution, but I am having issues thinking of a resolution.  I've pasted my cofunction below and as of now it only waits for the pressure to be within 10% so if it doesn't it is stuck there.  P.S. sorry if the code is sloppy I am a beginner and it is a work in progress.

```
cofunc run()
{
  if (status == 1 && fail() != 1)
     {
     waitfor (DelayMs(2000) || status==0);
     for (i; i<7; i++)
        {
      printf("\n\n In for loop in run psi[i] = %d", psi[i]);
      if (status == 0) return;
        if (psi[i] < 0 && psi[i-1] >= 0) // if negative and previous number positive
        {
         digOut(1,0);
          chamber = 1;
         waitfor (DelayMs(2000));
         digOut(1,1);
         }
       else if (psi[i] >= 0 && psi[i-1] < 0) // if positive and previous was negative
        {
         digOut(1,0);
          chamber = 2;
         waitfor (DelayMs(2000));
         digOut(1,1);
         }
      output = abs(psi[i]);
      output = output/7.23738;  // converts PSI to voltage
      if ((output) <= 5)  // makes sure that output voltage wont exceed 5 volts
          {
          anaOutVolts(0, output);
         waitfor (pressureb > (psi[i]*.9) && pressureb < (psi[i]*1.1));
         waitfor (DelayMs(time[i]));
          }
      } // end for statement
      return;
      }
    return;
}
```